# how to make Dynamic and interactive report using Developer Express Reporting?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to make my end users be able to edit an invoice report from the print preview.

i am wondering if it is possible to add a button edit to the report, so users can select a client from the clients list displayed in a look up edit window ?
or adding a text edit so users can write the product price for example ?

i have some pictures showing good examples about what i want to achieve but  unfortunately i cant upload them because i don't have enough reputation.

i tried to add some winform controls in a winContainer, but the controls shows no interactivity, the buttons can't be clicked and i can't write anything in the text box..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Report Parameters`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument4812).
Here is example:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create("String 1"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create("String 2"));
list.Add(Tuple.Create("String 3"));

var itemLabel = new XRLabel();
itemLabel.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", null, "Item1"));

var parameter = new Parameter();
parameter.Name = "UserText";
parameter.Type = typeof(string);
parameter.Value = "User text";
parameter.Description = "Enter Text: ";
parameter.Visible = true;

var parameterLabel = new XRLabel();
parameterLabel.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding(parameter, "Text", ""));
parameterLabel.TopF = 15;

var detail = new DetailBand();
detail.Controls.Add(itemLabel);
detail.Controls.Add(parameterLabel);

var report = new XtraReport();
report.DataSource = list;
report.Parameters.Add(parameter);
report.Bands.Add(detail);

var tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
tool.ShowRibbonPreview();
```

And in result of code above you will see `Parameters` panel:
[image: Parameters panel]

Answer (score 0):

You will use the   XRDesignRibbonForm  class.

```
XRDesignRibbonForm designForm = new XRDesignRibbonForm();
XtraReport yourReport = new XtraReport();

designForm.OpenReport(yourReport);
designForm.ShowDialog();
```

*The end users will edit the report and when they press the Save button they will save a *.repx file .

Then you can show the edited report with this code

```
XtraReport rr = XtraReport.FromFile("TheRepxFilePath", true);
ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(rr);
printTool.ShowRibbonPreview();
```

*With some work you can automate this process so that the end user does not have to select where the report will be saved so you can load and Preview the report later more easy

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but i don't want to give end users complete freedom to edit the report through the designer, i just want them to edit it through fields (buttons, textedits) that i specify. it is like filling a form (in print preview mode).

Comment: You can set the LockedInUserDesigner property of all controls to True and then set it to False on the editable controls